# Clear a div after console is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-inspection

I have found a code that clear certain div after a interval a time

```
var currentInnerHtml;
var element = new Image();
var elementWithHiddenContent = document.querySelector("#testDiv");
var innerHtml = elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML;

element.__defineGetter__("id", function () {
    currentInnerHtml = "";
});

setInterval(function () {
    currentInnerHtml = innerHtml;
    console.log(element);
    console.clear();
    elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML = currentInnerHtml;
}, 3000);
```

but what I need is to clear that div after DevTools is open, not from an interval of time.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You can edit your question and fix any typos, also not all browsers have functionality to detect such an event.

Comment: can try https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect